# httpUnit class not found

Tags: http, testing, scripting

I am trying httpUnit for the first time and just trying to get a response back from google.com.

However, I keep getting the following error:

`com.meterware.httpunit.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl not found`

Though, I have placed httpUnit.jar in the libraries folder of my NetBeans project and can actually see that class file is there.

Any experiences with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have to do with the [documented external dependencies](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/installing.html#dependencies) of HttpUnit.